# Mac OS X 's built-in VNC server disconnects me randomly, but frequently

Tags: macos, vnc, vncserver, connection

I've been using Mac OS X's VNC service to connect remotely from a Windows XP box, via TightVNC. Everything seems to work normally, except that frequently - anywhere from ten seconds to ten minutes - the connection locks up entirely, without any sort of error message. The only solution is to reconnect and wait for it to lock up again.

How can this be fixed permanently?

Comment: If your wifi on the mac dies *entirely* when you connect, a slightly different issue, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136802/vnc-connection-to-mavericks-screen-sharing-drops-wifi-connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out to be TightVNC's clipboard sharing. Whether this is a TightVNC or an OSX VNC server issue, I couldn't say. Disabling clipboard sharing in the TightVNC configuration made the problem go away entirely.